# Customize DLL search directory programmatically

Tags: c++, dll

I am writing a DLL in C++. My DLL will run with a third party software. And it loads another DLL (lets call it as LDLL) and this LDLL uses openssl.

But whenever my DLL tries to load my LDLL, it returns the error code 126.

I ran my LDLL with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and it showed the openssl dlls (ssleay.dll and libeay.dll) are missing. It is searching for these in some [standard folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx).

Are there any way programmatically to include my own search path in LDLL to load the openssl DLLs in my own search path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the `LoadLibrary` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The search path can be altered using [the `SetDllDirectory` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This solution is recommended instead of using `SetCurrentDirectory` or hard-coding the full path to the DLL.

But beware:

> Each time the `SetDllDirectory` function is called, it replaces the directory specified in the previous `SetDllDirectory` call. To specify more than one directory, use the `AddDllDirectory` function and call `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS`.

Another approach is to use delay-load of those libraries, and explicitly load them with `LoadLibrary` or `LoadLibraryEx` before using their functions.

Comment: Thanks, Can you add little more detail - The doc states "Adds a directory to the search path used to locate DLLs for the application.
" But it didn't state where it is going to add (at the end of the search path or at the beginning).

Comment: @Mohan: Actually, it does say "After calling `SetDllDirectory`, the standard DLL search path is: ...".  And it's neither at the beginning nor the end.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google for "Windows DLL search path" brings us [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), and I quote:

> With both implicit and explicit linking, Windows first searches for "known DLLs", such as Kernel32.dll and User32.dll. Windows then searches for the DLLs in the following sequence:
>
> 1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The Windows system directory. The `GetSystemDirectory` function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 4. The Windows directory.  The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.
>
> Note 
>   The LIBPATH environment variable is not used.

Comment: Thanks for the google search! My question is specific - Are there any way to modify this programatically and I requote "Are there any way to modify this search path to include the current directory where my DLL is located ? " My DLL might be in a different directory than those 5. Let me rephrase.

Comment: And I've already found this and even listed the specific directories via process monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645